# Cylinder alignment problem (beginner)

Tags: vertices

[image]
How do make the top [highlighted] vertices perfectly align with the bottom vertices along the x and y axis... so it looks like a smooth cylinder

Comment: I'd say create a new cylinder :D That's the easiest solution in this case. Or remove the op, extrude the bottom and move it up (G key, then Z key to constrain to Z axis movement) where the top was. You can leave 1 vertex, and then use snapping to snap to that vertex. There are some cool beginner tutorials like Blenderguru's donut/anvil/chair or e.g. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1jHUY3qoBu8